# How to specify a time interval between tasks in laravel queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to send Email using mandrill by using laravel queue without exceeding the hourly limit of mandrill (i.e 250/hr). So by that I can send only 4 mails a minute. I want to add delay to the tasks execution in the laravel queue. How can I do that ?

I tried `Queue::later` but it executes tasks with delay from the time of insertion.

P.S I'm using `beanstalk`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to handle it on your side with your application - Mandrill does it for you

> **Going over the hourly quota**
>
> If you send more than your quota in an hour, we won't delete the mail
>   - we'll just queue it until the next hour and then deliver it. By then your quota will likely have increased as we respond to your increased
>   volume.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21693468-Why-is-my-sending-quota-so-low-

Comment: Ok that's cool but is there any way I can configure my queue in laravel ?

Comment: The problem is that with Mandrill - they change your hourly limit dynamically. So the couple of times it might be 250mail/hr - but later in the day, once your reputation rises, it might be 350mail/hr. So if you configure something in Laravel to set a predefined amount per hour - then your causing other issues.

Comment: And the short answer is no - there is no 'process only 10 per hour' command for queues. You could write some custom code to do it, probably using some cache counter or something.